# SQL questions - Medium difficulty

Tags: sql, oracle

I am struggling on Q9 from this website: http://sqlzoo.net/a1m.htm

This is what I have put down at the moment even though I know it's not right

```
SELECT ID, 
       modle, 
       DOW, 
       TOD
  FROM event x
 WHERE modle = (SELECT modle
                  FROM event y
                 WHERE y.TOD = x.TOD)
```

Here is a link for the ER diagram: sqlzoo.net/a1.htm

What is the proper way to do this?

Comment: Don't forget to accept answers that satisfy you -- click the checkmark below the number, on the left side of the appropriate answer.

Answer (score 3):

The problem with this:

```
SELECT ID, modle, DOW, TOD 
  FROM event x 
 WHERE modle = (SELECT modle FROM event y WHERE y.TOD = x.TOD)
```

...is the subquery can return more than one row.  For such situations, you want to use `IN` rather than equals:

```
SELECT ID, modle, DOW, TOD 
  FROM event x 
 WHERE modle IN (SELECT modle FROM event y WHERE y.TOD = x.TOD)
```

Otherwise, you'll want to use either an aggregate or filter criteria to ensure a single record is always returned from the subquery.

I prefer using ANSI-92 JOIN syntax:

```
SELECT x.*
  FROM EVENT x
  JOIN EVENT y ON y.tod = x.tod
              AND y.modle = 'co72010'
```

### Using `IN`

```
SELECT x.*
  FROM EVENT x
 WHERE x.tod IN(SELECT y.tod 
                  FROM EVENT y
                 WHERE y.modle = 'co72010')
```

### Using `EXISTS`

```
SELECT x.*
  FROM EVENT x
 WHERE EXISTS(SELECT NULL
                FROM EVENT y
               WHERE y.modle = 'co72010'
                 AND y.tod = x.tod)
```

Comment: +1 for the detailed explanation. But you should take care of NULL values in *modle* or *tod* in the subselects when using `IN` otherwise it will give wrong results.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name: NULL in `modle` won't match based on the filtration.  And I though NULL in the IN clause will match x.tod's that are NULL?

Comment: @Ponies: I just tried it, NULL in the IN clause will not match x.tod's that are NULL.  Same as you can't do `WHERE MyNullableField=NULL`; rather, you have to use `IS NULL` (at least in SQL Server - could be wrong in Oracle, just noticed the tag)

Comment: you are right. IN is more robust regarding NULLs than NOT IN. Sorry for the noise

Answer (score 0):

You should try to use a join using twice the same table. Start with:

```
SELECT e2.id
FROM event AS e1, event AS e2
WHERE e1.modle = 'co72010'
AND …
```

I let you fill in the dots.